# Downgrade SQL query from MYSQL 8 to an eqivalent of MYSQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0

I have been testing this query on my localhost using MYSQL 8 but my hosting provider only offers MYSQL 5.7. I have been trying to find a way that I can write the same code in the older version of MYSQL.

```
SELECT SUM(COUNT(application.email)*temembers.referral_bonus) OVER() AS total_count FROM application
            LEFT JOIN members ON members.re_link=application.aff_code
            WHERE application.re_status='1' AND MONTH(application.completed_paydate)='$month'
```

This is the other query while using OVER(PARTITION BY)

```
SELECT aff_members.app_full_name, COUNT(application.email) AS NumberOfRe, SUM(COUNT(application.email)*members.re_bonus) OVER(PARTITION BY application.aff_code) AS total_count FROM application
        LEFT JOIN members ON members.re_link=application.aff_code
        WHERE application.re_status='1' AND MONTH(application.completed_paydate)<='$last_month'
        GROUP BY app_email
```

I have tried to find an alternative for combining rows using OVER(), but I have not found any for MYSQL 5.7.

Comment: Can you share input tables and expected output?

Comment: You need a new hosting provider.  5.7 is very close to end of life when it will no longer receive security updates.

Comment: Is it possible your hosting provider is switching to mariadb?  There are only a few improvements in 5.7 that are not in mariadb.  Mariadb supports window functions beginning in 10.2.